# WSDL: Function 'foo' doesn't exist

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I am in the process of developing a WSDL for my SOAP API, and I've run into a bit of an issue.

I started off with a single `operation`, and it worked fine. But as soon as I added another `operation`, I'm getting a rather weird error.

Consider the following (stripped down for brevity):

```
<message name="doSomethingRequest">
   <part name="foo" type="xsd:integer" />
</message>

...

<portType name="myServicePort">
    <operation name="doSomething">
        <input message="tns:doSomethingRequest" />
        <output message="tns:doSomethingResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

...

<binding name="myServiceBinding" type="tns:myServicePort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="doSomething">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                namespace="urn:mygroup:myservice" use="encoded" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

I am consuming this service using PHP in a very simple manner:

```
$ws = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
$result = $ws->doSomething(1);
```

Now the problem stems from something in the WSDL, not the PHP. I have verified this by changing the `<part name="foo" ... />` to `<part name="bar" ... />`, and the SoapFault then changes to `Function 'bar' doesn't exist`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's on a private network, but it points to my full WSDL.

Comment: Upon calling `$ws->__getLastRequest()`, I'm seeing that the request is actually: `<foo xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</foo>`